How to automate Incident Management broadcast emails
The Incident Management feature includes an option to send Broadcast Emails to a list view of Contacts, using what appears to be it's own 5000 emails-per-day limit (in testing, sending Apex emails doesn't impact the number of Incident emails available).  I can only find documentation on sending these emails via the UI, but we'd like to build some automation for ongoing updates during an incident.  Is there any way to automate these emails, either via Apex or Flow?  Ideally we'd like to use the Broadcast Emails limits instead of the generic Apex Email limits.

Upon further research and testing, it appears that the Broadcast Emails feature is using the existing MassEmail limit, not a separate limit.  If we need to send via Apex, we can simply use MassEmailMessage, and potentially create the BroadcastCommunication and related objects via code, for record keeping.
